# how to catch datas in this swaptree code?

Tags: c, tree, swap

this code is written by its creator's favour .
i want to give the code my actual numbers as many as i want .
i realised that i would have to do something like this :
    root->left->left->left 
 to create more levels

but how can i put my idea in this code if i want to create more levels ??

i mean continuing this term is just wasting time !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
     int data;
     struct node* left;
     struct node* right;
};

struct node* newNode(int data)
{
     struct node* node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     node->data = data;
     node->left = NULL;
     node->right = NULL;
     return(node);
}

void printInorder(struct node* node)
{
     if (node == NULL)
          return;
     printInorder(node->left);
     printf("%d ", node->data); 
     printInorder(node->right);
}


void swapTree(struct node*node)
{
    if(node==NULL) return;
    struct node*temp=node->left;
    node->left=node->right;
    node->right=temp;
    swapTree(node->left);
    swapTree(node->right);
}
int main()
{
     struct node *root  = newNode(1);
     root->left             = newNode(2);
     root->right           = newNode(3);
     root->left->left     = newNode(4);
     root->left->right   = newNode(5);
     printf("\n Inorder traversal of binary tree is \n");
     printInorder(root); 
     swapTree(root);
     printf("\n After swap Inorder traversal of binary tree is \n");
     printInorder(root); 

      return 0; 
}
```

Comment: question or the code has nothing to do with inheritance

Comment: You usually use recursion (or loops) to traverse the tree and then insert/delete/change nodes.

Comment: you have probably write code for inserting node

Comment: as you can see in the code 
the data is given in the code . 
i want to use scanf() and catch them from user . as many as user wants .

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along the lines of:

```
int value;
scanf("%d", &value);
struct node *inputNode = newNode(value);
```

After this, `inputNode` will point to a node with `value` as its `data` field. You would need to implement a function that takes this pointer and inserts it in the tree at the right location. That will depend on the type of tree you're implementing.

Comment: i tried that .but i didn't success . i want that user choose the left or right side of the previous node and then i add the new one to its right or left side of it .

Comment: Well in that case, you will have to accept three values from the user: an input key, a search key, and a flag to indicate if it is a left or a right child. You will also have to write another function to search the tree for the search key, and change its left or right child pointer to the new node. If the search node already has children, you will have to account for that too.